# A strong key is changed by add: in NSArrayController. Why?

Tags: macos, cocoa, key, automatic-ref-counting, nsarraycontroller

If an `NSArrayController` is bound to an array that is generated using

```
@synthesize (strong) anArray;
```

very strange things happen when using the `add:` or `remove:` bindings. For example, I end up with a different address for anArray. I am sure this has to do with the **strong** keyword. Can someone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:arc] tag for questions related to apple's automatic-reference-counting. Instead, use the [tag:automatic-ref-counting] tag.

Comment: I had no idea, my apologies. Looking at your link I can see why. I do admit I was pleasantly surprised by the number of followers for "arc" :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you binding the `NSArrayController` to an `NSArray`, or an `NSMutableArray`? `NSArrayController` with work if you bind it to an `NSArray`, but because the array is immutable the array controller will create a new array every time you add or remove objects.

Comment: That makes sense, I will double check asap. But I do think it may be a mutable array, since an `NSArray` just would not make sense in my app!